# Speeding up a function

Tags: r, optimization, data.table, lapply

I want to calculate the first differences for a large panel data set. At the moment this however takes more than an hour. I am really curious to know if there are still any options left to speed up the process. As an example database:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.table(panelID = sample(50,50),                                                    # Creates a panel ID
                      Country = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",50), rep("C",20)),                      
                      Group = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = sample(100,100),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))           
DF [, uniqueID := .I]
```

So what I have tried is the following:

```
DFx <- DF
start_time <- Sys.time()
    DF <- DF[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x)), by = panelID, .SDcols = (sapply(DF, is.numeric))]
end_time <- Sys.time()
DF <- DFx
start_time2 <- Sys.time()
    cols = sapply(DF, is.numeric)
    DF <- DF[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x)), by = panelID, .SDcols = cols]
end_time2 <- Sys.time()
DF <- DFx
start_time3 <- Sys.time()
DF <- DF[order(panelID)] # Sort on year
nm1 <- sapply(DF, is.numeric) # Get the numerical columns  
nm1 = names(nm1) 
nm2 <- paste("delta", nm1, sep="_")[-6] # Paste
DF <- DF[,(nm2) := .SD - shift(.SD), by=panelID] # Creates 
end_time3 <- Sys.time()
end_time3 - start_time3
end_time2 - start_time2
end_time - start_time
```

For some reason the third option works on my actual database, but not for this example. It gives the error: `Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. For my actual database this way of calculating was also rather slow (and then I still have to subset).

Any ideas how to make this faster?

Comment: Why are you not using the `diff` function?

Comment: I got these option from previous question I have posted. Is `diff` faster?

Comment: I don't see anything particularly problematic with your first option when setting `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)`. I'm actually amazed that this is taking so long. Your number of `panelID` must be huge.

Comment: `function(x) c(NA, diff(x))` appears to be twice as fast if I increase the size of the input data.table.

Comment: @Roland, it is (at least I think it is a lot). It is about 100.000 observations for two periods.

Comment: The problem is not the number of observations. It is the number of groups in `by`. However, with your example data (after increasing the number of groups to 50k) it takes less than three seconds. How can it take more than an hour with your data? You should do some profiling with a subsample of your data and find out where that time is spent. Are you perhaps on a system that starts swapping memory to disk?

Comment: I understand (but I thought this was the easiest way to write down the size). Probably because there are also almost a 1000 variables.

Comment: Umm, **very** relevant. `melt` your data.table so that you don't need `lapply`.

Comment: @Roland Is there any possibility you could show me how? I am running with `function(x) c(NA, diff(x))` now, but I am not sure how to use the `melt` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data.table is optimized for many rows, not for many columns. Since you have many columns, you could try melting the data.table:

```
DFm <- melt(DF[, cols, with = FALSE][, !"uniqueID"], id = "panelID") 
#coerces all numers to double (common type), 
#you could separate the data.table by integer/double to avoid this

DFm[, value := c(NA, diff(value)), by = .(panelID, variable)]


dcast(DFm, panelID + rowidv(DFm, cols = c("panelID", "variable")) ~ variable, value.var = "value")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Roland. This is super helpful. I am trying it right now, but when apply the `melt` I am getting the error: `Error in `[.data.table`(DF, , cols, with = FALSE) : 
  Item 10 of j is 12 which is outside the column number range [1,ncol=11]` and I am not exactly sure why this happens (or how to find that out). Any ideas from the top of your head?

Comment: Clearly, there is the number 12 in `cols` but you only have 11 columns in `DF`.

Comment: Sorry I am an idiot, I overlooked `cols` being used (and not being specified). It works now!

Comment: @Tom By how much did this speed-up your use case?

Comment: It is almost 4 times as fast. Amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: So, about 15 minutes? That's still quite slow. If I'd need this often, I'd write a function with Rcpp.

Comment: @Roland agree, sounds slow. There are plans for speeding up melt/dcast.

Comment: @jangorecki But that's not the bottleneck here. There is just a massive number of groups in by.