# Creating single column dataframe with the means of another dataset

Tags: r, syntax, data.table, summary

I have a dataset which looks as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.table(panelID = sample(50,50),                                                    # Creates a panel ID
                      Country = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",50), rep("C",20)),                      
                      Group = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = sample(100,100),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))           
DF [, uniqueID := .I]     
DF <- as.data.table(DF)                                                 # Make sure it is a data.table 
DF [, uniqueID := .I]                                                   # Add a unique ID
cols = sapply(DF, is.numeric)                                           # Check numerical columns
DFm <- melt(DF[, cols, with = FALSE][, !"uniqueID"], id = "panelID")    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406654/speeding-up-a-function/57407959#57407959
DFm[, value := c(NA, diff(value)), by = .(panelID, variable)]           # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406654/speeding-up-a-function/57407959#57407959
DF <- dcast(DFm, panelID + rowidv(DFm, cols = c("panelID", "variable")) ~ variable, value.var = "value") # ""
DF <- DF[DF[, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD , is.na)), .SDcols = 3:ncol(DF)]] # Removes T1 for which there is no difference
```

Now what I would like to do is fairly simple. I want the mean of each column stored in a single column.

[image]

I tried:

```
mean_of_differences <- DF [, mean(sapply(.SD, is.numeric), na.rm=TRUE)]   
mean_of_differences <- DF[,.SD[mean(sapply(.SD, is.numeric), na.rm=TRUE)]]
```

But somehow I cannot seems to get it right. I just end up with NA's or errors.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Is this what you need? `DF[,lapply(.SD,mean)]`?

Comment: Haha, that could very well be, but where do I specify to not include the NA's, and where do I specify that it should only pick numerical columns (I need this for the actual dataset)?

Comment: There might be a simpler way: `DF[,lapply(Filter(is.integer,.SD),mean, na.rm=TRUE)]` Used int since all seem to be numeric.

Comment: One more thing.. If I would want to take the mean of the squared or absolute values. Where would I put `abs` / `sqrt` ?

Comment: I think you can use a lambda within the lapply.  Something like(purely demonstrative): `DF[,lapply(Filter(is.integer,.SD),function(x) mean(abs(x)/sqrt(x),na.rm=TRUE))]`. There might be more elegant ways.